# Problems in RAID not being reported by Nagios/Icinga - using check_raid

Tags: raid, nagios, icinga

I am running the check_raid script on a number of machines and I just noticed today that one of my machines was in a degraded state but I was not being alerted. The script is returning "CRITICAL" but Icinga sees it as ok.

Here's what I'm seeing on my Icinga machine (I have replaced the disk):

```
SNMP OK - "CRITICAL: tw_cli:[c3(9650SE-4LPML): u0(RAID-10): REBUILDING 65%, Cache:Ri, Drives(4): p2=DEGRADED p0,p1,p3=OK]"
```

The configuration for this machine is very simple:

```
define service{
use generic-service
host_name test
service_description RAID Status
check_command check_raid
}
```

Here's the command definition:

```
define command{
command_name    check_raid
command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -o ucdavis.80.3.1.1.13.47.117.115.114.47.98.105.110.47.112.101.114.108 -C public -r "OK"
```

And on the machine being checked I have the following in the snmpd.conf:

```
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.80 /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/check_raid.pl
```

I'm using the latest version of the script, anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? Is the -r "OK" always returning an ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nagios script is matching 3 of your 4 return conditions, which is why it returns OK.

From [check_snmp documentation](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_snmp.html):

```
-r, --ereg=REGEX
   Return OK state (for that OID) if extended regular expression REGEX matches
```

Your script returns the following (edited by me for brevity):

```
"CRITICAL: [...] p2=DEGRADED p0,p1,p3=OK]"
```

The `check_snmp` sees p0, p1, p3 are OK and returns `OK`, ignoring p2

I would try it without the `-r "OK"` and confirm you get the results you expect.  If the incorrect return result persists, I would experiment with `--invert-search`:

```
 --invert-search
    Invert search result (CRITICAL if found)
```

Comment: That was it - I didn't understand what the -r was doing. I have changed my command to:

command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -o ucdavis.80.3.1.1.13.47.117.115.114.47.98.105.110.47.112.101.114.108 -C public -r "CRITICAL" --invert-search

Now it works properly:

SNMP CRITICAL - *"CRITICAL: tw_cli:[c3(9650SE-4LPML): u0(RAID-10): REBUILDING 94%, Cache:Ri, Drives(4): p2=DEGRADED p0,p1,p3=OK]"*

Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear!  Yes, I was going to edit and  suggest -`r "DEGRADED" --invert-search` (or replace "DEGRADED" with the condition for which you want to receive a critical alert.  Glad you found a fix.